# How to check if a variable is a Timeout in Javascript?

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I decided to contain this code into an object to separate it out from the areas it will be applied. Any advice here is really appreciated:

**appConfig.loadElement and appConfig.cerrorElement are these HTML elements:**

```
<div id="loading" style="display:none;">Loading...</div>
<div id="cerror" style="display:none;">Connection Error.</div>


var loadingTimeoutInstance = null, cerrorTimeoutInstance = null,
    requestObj = {
    reset: function() {
        $(appConfig.loadElement).hide();
        $(appConfig.cerrorElement).hide();
        clearTimeout(loadingTimeoutInstance);
        clearTimeout(cerrorTimeoutInstance);
    },
    initiate: function() {
        loadingTimeoutInstance = setTimeout(requestObj.timeout, appConfig.loadingDelayMS);
    },
    timeout: function () {
        clearTimeout(loadingTimeoutInstance);
        $(appConfig.loadElement).show();
        cerrorTimeoutInstance = setTimeout(requestObj.cerror, appConfig.cerrorDelayMS);
    },
    cerror: function () {
        clearTimeout(cerrorTimeoutInstance);
        $(appConfig.loadElement).hide();
        $(appConfig.cerrorElement).show();
    }
}
```

An implementation is like so:

When an asynchronous request is made:

```
requestObj.reset();
requestObj.initiate();
```

After the response is returned:

```
requestObj.reset();
```

The problems I have identified are mainly in requestObj.reset():
- Why hide elements if they are already hidden?
- Can't clear the timeout vars (loadingTimeoutInstance and cerrorTimeoutInstance) if they are not set as timeouts yet - this causes it not to work.

Comment: There is generally no problem "re-hiding" an element; it saves a check (that would not change the semantics) as only the final state is cared about. The last bit is confusing though: "if they are not set as timeouts yet ... causes it not to work" ... in what way does it not work? Have a fiddle test-case?

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't work when I clear the timeout that has not been set. I've had this issue a few other times, this case is one of them. ahren's solution works great, though. And about hiding an element that is already hidden- it just bothers me because this logically makes no sense, I know that the result is not affected. Thanks for your advice:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't actually need to check if it's of a certain type... just that it is.

`if(cerrorTimeoutInstance) clearTimeout(cerrorTimeoutInstance);`

Comment: You don't even need this check. `clearTimeout` will happily "do nothing" if passed `null`, `undefined` or `"chocolate is good"`. However, prudence dictates that the timeout ID is forgotten as it could *technically* be re-used... (I would imagine most implementations make this "difficult to do" but have not checked.)

Comment: Further to pst's comment, after the call to `clearTimeout(cerrorTimeoutInstance)` the variable `cerrorTimeoutInstance` will still hold the same value (it's just a number used as an ID). There's no way to tell if the timeout for a given ID has already run or previously been cleared, though as pst implied it's unlikely the same ID will be re-used so it is safe to call `clearTimeout()` again for the same ID.